# Google App Engine mail.Send returns "TypeError: unhashable instance" in python2.7/smtplib.py

Tags: python, google-app-engine, go, smtp, sendmail

I am trying to locally send mail via Google App Engine Development Server:

```
dev_appserver.py --show_mail_body true --smtp_host=xxx --smtp_port=25 --smtp_user=xxx --smtp_password=xxx app.yaml


if err := mail.Send(c, &mail.Message{
    Sender:  "xxx@xxx.com",
    To:       []string{"xxx@xxx.com"},
    Subject:  "Test",
    Body:     "Text Body",
    HTMLBody: "HTML Body",
}); err != nil {
    c.Errorf("%v", err)
}
```

Unfortunately this results in the following error:

```
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/smtplib.py", line 731, in sendmail
    senderrs[each] = (code, resp)
TypeError: unhashable instance
```

Can somebody please help me fix this? `--enable_sendmail true` works btw. [Traceback](https://gist.github.com/mattes/b6f0108bec471e223e7b).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That bit of `smtplib.py` is handling an error from `rcpt()`, which has tried sending `rcpt TO:xxx@xxx.com` to smtp. So there are two issues: what's `rcpt` complaining about, and what's with the `unhashable instance`. For the latter, I recommend filing a bug report. The code shouldn't do that. For the former, it'd be really tempted to put some simple `print` debugging into `smtplib.py` right above `senderrs[each] = (code, resp)`. There might be some simple upstream error that smpt is showing you, the bypassing of which might obviate the need to sort out the unhashable instance (which I'm guessing is caused by code on the GAE side).

Comment: Thanks for the ``print`` advice. In fact the SMTP server returned an error: "Sender address rejected: not owned by user xxx" I changed the sender (which was obviously my fault) and it works now.

Comment: Following up: if I change it to ``senderrs[str(each)] = (code, resp)`` I'll get the correct error. This is probably a bug in the smtplib. Not sure if the ``str(each)`` is the best fix though.